# Is the value in the distance function being retained?

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures

I am trying to find the distance between two nodes.
In my specific case, the distance between two nodes is the no of edges between the nodes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace bhargav;


int distance(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* n1)
{
   static int height = -1;
   
   if (root == NULL)
      return -1;

   if (root == n1)
      return ++height;  

   int left = distance(root->left, n1);
   
   if (left >= 0)
      return ++height;

   int right = distance(root->right, n1);
   
   if (right >= 0)
      return ++height;

   return height;
}

int main()
{
   TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(1);
   root->left = new TreeNode(2);
   root->right = new TreeNode(3);
   root->right->left = new TreeNode(4);
   root->right->right = new TreeNode(5);
   std::cout << distance(root->right, root->right->left) << "\n";
   
   std::cout << distance(root->right, root->right->right) << "\n";
   
}
```

1. If I call the statement
   `std::cout << distance(root->right, root->right->left) << "\n"; // 1`
   in the main function, I get 1 as output.
2. If I call the statement
   `std::cout << distance(root->right, root->right->right) << "\n"; // 1`
   in the main function, I get 1 as output.
3. However f I call both statements

```
std::cout << distance(root->right, root->right->left) << "\n"; // 1
std::cout << distance(root->right, root->right->right) << "\n"; // 2
```

I get 1 and 2 as output, I want to find the underlying cause of the change in output.

Comment: PSA: In C++ prefer `nullptr` to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: Why the use of `static int` in `distance()`?

Comment: Static data is a problem. Do not use static data.

Comment: When Ever I increment height in a recursive function call it retains the value during each invocation of the function and finally when I return height it returns the updated height value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `static` local variable will be shared between *all* calls to the function. It's initialized *once*, and only once. You can't call the function twice and expect the function to initialize it again.

In fact, from the compilers point of view there's really no difference between calls to a function: A function call is a function call is a function call... Recursion is not something the compiler knows or cares about, it's all just the same call.

To solve the problem of `distance` not being possible to call multiple times (from the "top" level), you can use a *helper* function to do the actual work, and a `distance` function which defines `height` as a normal non-static variable, initializes it, and passes it as an argument to the helper function.

Perhaps something like this:

```
int distance_helper(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* n1, int& height)
{
    // ...
    int left = distance_helper(root->left, n1, height);
    // ...
}

int distance(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* n1)
{
    int height = -1;
    return distance_helper(root, n1, height);
}
```